# Order first div behind second one

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I wonder if there is possible to set the first div behind the second one without use jquery or flex box.

Is there any way ?

```css
.container {}

.one {
  background-color: #FF0004;
  float: right;
}

.two {
  background-color: #000DFF;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos vitae nihil facere repudiandae voluptatem corporis tempore quasi? A quo aspernatur odit expedita cum maxime, alias quis. Laudantium quaerat voluptatem quo.</div>

    <div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, eos. Quas nihil tenetur suscipit asperiores obcaecati fuga, id, quis dolor quisquam explicabo modi optio unde! Quas atque eius, numquam aliquam.</div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Give parent div `position:relative` and `position:absolute` to child div.
Now you can handle the position of div using `top:10px` and `left:10px`.

```css
.container {
position:relative;
}
.one {
    background-color: #FF0004;
    float: right;
}
.two {
    background-color: #000DFF;
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos vitae nihil facere repudiandae voluptatem corporis tempore quasi? A quo aspernatur odit expedita cum maxime, alias quis. Laudantium quaerat voluptatem quo.</div>

    <div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, eos. Quas nihil tenetur suscipit asperiores obcaecati fuga, id, quis dolor quisquam explicabo modi optio unde! Quas atque eius, numquam aliquam.</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **z-index**

```css
.container {}

.one {
  background-color: #FF0004;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.two {
  background-color: #000DFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos vitae nihil facere repudiandae voluptatem corporis tempore quasi? A quo aspernatur odit expedita cum maxime, alias quis. Laudantium quaerat voluptatem quo.</div>

  <div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, eos. Quas nihil tenetur suscipit asperiores obcaecati fuga, id, quis dolor quisquam explicabo modi optio unde! Quas atque eius, numquam aliquam.</div>

</div>
```